# Convergence of the Bootstrap to the true mean

Tags: bootstrap, convergence, central-limit-theorem

Suppose that $X_i,$ $i= 1, 2 \dots$ are iid with finite positive variance,

then let $X_{i,n}^*$ $(i = 1, \dots, m)$ be a bootstrap sample of size m from $\lbrace X_1, \dots, X_n\rbrace$, then
    \begin{equation}
 \sqrt{m} \left( \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i = 1}^m X_{i,n}^*  - \frac{1}{n} \sum _{i = 1}^n X_i\right) \longrightarrow N(0, \sigma^2) \text{ as } m \text{ and } n \rightarrow \infty 
 \end{equation}
    we also have that:
    \begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{n} \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i  - \mu \right)\longrightarrow N(0, \sigma^2) \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty 
 \end{equation*}
    by the central limit theorem.
    Then my question is do we also have that if $m = n$:
    \begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{n} \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n X_{i,n}^*  - \mu\right) \longrightarrow N(0, 2\sigma^2) \text{ as } n \longrightarrow \infty?
 \end{equation*}

Now, ideally I'd like to add the two sort of, however lack of independence and different m, n indices makes this difficult.

I tried simulating some data in R and I compared QQplots from which this seemed to hold, however possibly this is under certain conditions.

Comment: Your first line is not actually correct, as the $\sigma^2$ on the right of the $\rightarrow$ is a population number but, given a particular sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$, the variance of the sample - which is the relevant number here - need not equal $\sigma^2$.

Comment: @jbowman Yeah you're right, I meant n  to go to infinity here too, I've edited the question, thanks.

Comment: You could restrict the problem somewhat by making $m = \alpha n$ for some fixed $\alpha  > 0$, well floor or ceiling to preserve integers, then you only have to have $n \to \infty$.   But that might be more limiting than you want.

Comment: Yeah that's true, in fact I'm most interested in the n = m case, or the a = 1 case. However, while I'd like to add the first two equations, because they're not independent, I don't know how to show that the third one holds under this assumption.

Comment: I admit I'm writing comments instead of doing the hard work to answer the question, but... it seems to me if you altered eq. 1 to have $s^2$ instead of $\sigma^2$ and got rid of the $n$ in $m, n \to \infty$, then use the fact that $s^2 \to \sigma^2$ as $n \to \infty$, you would get independence, because eq. 1 is true regardless of the actual value of $1/n \sum X_i$ (in some sense.)

Comment: Sorry @jbowman, I've only just seen your comment. Well correct me if I'm wrong but I think you need independence between the left hand sides of the equation and not the right hand side. So under your suggestion of using s^2 instead of $\sigma^2$, the LHS of eq1 still depends on 1/n \sum X_i which is in the LHS of eqn 2, so they are not independent.